# Converting decimal with comma to binary

Tags: math, binary, decimal

I'm trying to convert decimal numbers with commas into binary. I've seen that if you have for example the number 5.2 in decimal you convert it to 101.10, since 5 is 101 and 2 is 10 but I've seen a method that I don't quite understand.

For example, the number 93.3125 is 0000 0101 1101 0101. Why ?
Are there other methods that help you transform decimals with comma into binary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle each part (before and after decimal point) separately. The integer part is converted by consequent division by base and the decimal part by consequent multiplying by base. In your case `base = 2`:

```
5.2 dec -> 5 + 0.2 dec
```

**Integer part**

```
5 % 2 = 1 // binary digit
5 / 2 = 2 // leftover for next iteration

2 % 2 = 0 // binary digit
2 / 2 = 1 // leftover for next iteration

1 % 2 = 1 // binary digit
1 / 2 = 0 // leftover for next iteration
```

Do not forget that the digits has to be used in reverse order (your 5 is the same however):

```
5 dec = 1 0 1 bin
```

**Decimal part**

```
0.2 * 2 = 0.4   
0.4 * 2 = 0.8   
0.8 * 2 = 1.6
0.6 * 2 = 1.2
0.2 * 2 = 0.4
...
```

All is in decadic. The integer part of result is your digit (in order) and the decimal part is leftover for next iteration. So the result is:

```
0.2 dec = 0 . 0 0 1 1 0 ... bin
```

Putting together:

```
5.2 dec = 101.00110... bin
```

Comment: Why did you multiply 0.2 with 2, and why did you write 0.2 * 2 = 1.4 ? I don't quite understand how to transform 0.2 dec in bin

Comment: @David 1. because decimal part (after decimal point) of `5.2` is `0.2` and the `2` is your base as you wanted to convert to binary numbers. So you simply multiply the decimal part of number by base (2) the integer part of result is a digit of the output and the decimal part you multiply by base again in the same manner... repeat this until you have enough digits or the leftover is zero. 2. The `0.2*2` is `0.4` I forget to remove the 1 as I copy pasted it from previous line have repaired it already

Comment: @David if you want a quick check then type `5.2*256` into calculator, convert the integer part of the result to binary and then just put decimal point so there is `8` digits after it ...  `5.2*256 = 1331 dec -> 10100110011 bin ->  5.2 dec = 101.00110011` ... because `2^8 = 256` if you want more bits use bigger number like `1024 = 2^10` ...this is called fixed point math

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of ways to convert a decimal number into a string of 1s and 0s. You have just demonstrated two of them.

If you convert the number (represented in *base-10 place notation)* `93.3125` into "binary" (represented in *base-2 place notation)* you get `1011101.0101`

If you convert it into a a binary floating-point format used in a computer language, you get a string of 1s and 0s, perhaps with a leading bit indicating sign, and some other bits for exponent -- you'll need a format description document to decode it.

Translating "5.2" into "101.10" (translating the parts before and after the decimal point separately) is a new one on me, and it is *not* a mathematically correct translation of place notation. "5"=>"101" is correct, but ".2"=>".10" is not; ".2" in decimal is two tenths, a.k.a. one fifth, which in base two is ".001100110011..." (one fifth is a repeating decimal in base two, just as one third is a repeating decimal in base ten.) And how would you translate "1.02"?

So yes, there are plenty of ways to *encode* a number in binary. Different codes are useful in different ways.

Comment: I don't quite understand when to put the comma for 93.3125. Why is it 0101 after the comma ? On top of that, why is .2, 001100110011 ?

Comment: @David: Do you understand base-two notation? How would you represent one half? Or one quarter, or one eighth, or one sixteenth, or 2^-n?